# Why can't I say "to regain my mood"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I was asking whether I could use the phrase in the title in the different site and there was an English native speaker that didn't understand what I was trying to say. So, I suppose the usage of this word is utterly wrong or very unusual?

In OALD, the first definition of this word defines **regain** as *to get back something you no longer have, especially **an ability or a quality.***

E.g.

- I struggled to regain some **dignity**.

They suggested using "to improve my mood" in one example. Can't I consider **mood** as either **an ability** or **a quality** in this context? In short, is the phrase "to regain my mood" definitely wrong?

Comment: *Your mood*, without further qualification, is how you feel now. You haven't lost it, so you can't regain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the verb "regain" with the direct object "mood" is grammatically correct and easily understandable, but other expressions are more common.

If your original mood were one of equanimity but worsened temporarily, then we would more often say that you "regained your composure". (You can also say that your mood "improved", although, of course, that doesn't include the idea of "regaining".)

If you regained a different mood, then you could phrase the sentence differently. E.g.:

> I calmed down briefly, but then I regained my anger. <-- Possible but uncommon
> I calmed down briefly, but then I became angry again. <-- Much more common